# Access click event in parent window

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to use a ckeditor file browser outside the wysiwyg editor. When I'm clicking on an image in the parent, file browser, window the window closes. When using the editor the image path is inserted in a text field inside ckeditor. I wan't the same functionality but in a regular text field.

I've managed to open the file browser window when my textfield is clicked on:

```
$('input.asset_field').click(function() {
  window.open('/ckeditor/pictures','BrowseWindow','toolbar=no,status=no,resizable=yes,dependent=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=900,height=505');              
});
```

And when I select an image the file browser is closed. **BUT** how do I get the image path? This is driving me crazy! :)

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

if you define a function within the page that opens the pop like

```
function setUrl(url) {
    //some logic
}
```

you can call the follwing from the popup page

```
window.opener.setUrl(theUrlYouClicked);
```